# Creating a dual of a plannar Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Im looking at this [pdf](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.889/fall11/lectures/L11.pdf) as im trying to build an MSSP(multiple source shortest path) but im lacking the knowledge  how to built interdegitating trees. until now i created the Spanning tree therefore the plannar graph is created, but im stuck cause i have no idea how i will build its dual. Is there any specific algorithm/approach or any paper which could help me solve this? As i searched and could find nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you don't have one already, you need a combinatorial embedding. There are efficient algorithms to obtain one from the incidence structure, but natural sources of planar graphs typically have a natural embedding. There are many ways to represent the embedding. I used a permutation π mapping each half-edge to the next half-edge in counterclockwise order with the same head vertex. With each (non-isolated) vertex is associated a circularly linked list of incoming half-edges.
2. Let rev be the permutation that maps each half-edge to its other half, with opposite head and tail vertices. The embedding permutation for the dual graph is the composition of π followed by rev. It maps each half-edge to the next half-edge on the face in clockwise order (or counterclockwise on the infinite face, because you're looking at its back side). This will be clearer if you try some examples by hand.
3. After you compute shortest paths from the initial root (I used Dijkstra, and unless your MSSP implementation is much faster than mine, there isn't much relative improvement to be had by using an asymptotically faster algorithm), do a depth-first search where the edges that belong to the shortest-path tree are ignored. (Another alternative is to visit the half-edges of the interdigitating tree in Euler-tour order, but this approach seemed as though it would incur extra logarithmic-time dynamic-tree operations.)

Comment: according to papers found online i could create the plannar graph by the use of an euler tour graph therefore i arranged the code such that every change could be done in log n. As it is with dynamic trees. If you used dijkstra it would imply that you would have n^2 * n^2 complexity. Yes but im finding it hard to understand how the operations of the euler tour raph will work with the link/cut tree. As they can be used as interdigitating trees. Since euler graphs cant store info about the paths. thanks alot for the help :)

Comment: 1. I use Dijkstra only once, during initialization. The asymptotic running time for MSSP is still O(n log n). There's a linear-time shortest-path algorithm for planar graphs, but since computing the initial shortest-path tree is a tiny fraction of the overall running time, there isn't much improvement to be had even if the running time of that step were zero. 2. Euler tour trees are not appropriate because they do not support path operations. I meant that you can enumerate the half-edges of the interdigitating tree without using a stack.